# how to store timestamp in google sheet when user submit data in custom web form

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I am currently created a custom web form and storing the data from the form in google sheet, but i am not able find way to save timestamp in google sheet

Can anyone tell me script or code for saving the timestamp when user click submit

Answer (score 0):

With regard to timestamp you have to manually add your JS code to generate the time. There's no sheetsv4 method to generate that for you so use [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) upon clicking submit to generate the exact time.

**Syntax**

```
var timeInMs = Date.now();
```

**Description**

> Because now() is a static method of Date, you always use it as
>   Date.now().
>
> Polyfill This method was standardized in ECMA-262 5th edition. Engines
>   which have not been updated to support this method can work around the
>   absence of this method using the following shim:

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```